# How to get REST response size in Karate?

Tags: karate

In Karate framework using Visual studio, I am making a REST call. I need to get the response size in KB or MB.

I tried these:

1. - print response.size

Response: [jdk.dynalink.beans.SimpleDynamicMethod int java.util.HashMap.size()]

2. - print response.length

Response: 6
This is the # of nodes of the response (items,hasMore,count,limit,offset,links)

3. - print responseHeaders

Response: This gives me the response headers. It does not have response size

Can someone suggest a way to get the response size?

Answer (score 0):

The [`responseBytes`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#responsebytes) will contain the raw bytes and you can get the JavaScript `length` property like this:

```
* print 'size:', responseBytes.length
```

Note that I am using Karate version 1.X

Comment: I tried this. I got value as 47123. When I checked response size on Postman, I got 4.06 KB. I am not sure this matches.

Comment: @AbhijitKulkarni then please use Postman :) note that extra headers will  cause a difference. finally if you feel there is a bug please follow this process (exactly as described): https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue